# Best website for checking PNR status for Indian Railways

Tags: tickets, online-resources, india, indian-railways

Many times when we train, we get waiting tickets. But to check PNR status, there are few websites which are always down. One is http://www.pnrstatusupdate.in

Any more website to check PNR status?

Answer (score 8):

[Indian Rail website](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html) .If you have booked online through IRCTC website, you can check it through there itself.

A point to remember, if the Indian railways network is down, it doesn't help if you use their site or some other site, as all data update comes from the Indian railways network. Any reason not using the railway's website ?

Answer (score 6):

**Suggested Site:**

Get all the information instantly from [eRail](http://erail.in/) website, this website is maintained by **CRIS** (*Centre for Railway Information Systems*)

The advantage of this site is this doesn't require a *Login* or a *Captcha*, its fast and convenient and not only the PNR status but you can check all other information about trains such as train inquiry, seat availability etc.

Additionally `erail.in` extension is available for *Chrome/Firefox* which will enhance your browsing experience with their website.

**Other sites:**

http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html (No Login, Captcha required)

Comment: Who are CRIS? Something to do with the Indian Railways? Or a random private company?

Comment: CRIS developed IRCTC website. Centre for Railway Information Systems is CRIS

Comment: You should edit this into your answer - it makes it better!

Comment: Yes, its done.. Now please upvote if you like it :)

Answer (score 4):

The website that dumbcoder mentioned is obviously the first place you can go however just to ensure that this question is answered more comprehensively, http://irctc.co.in which is the site you use to book your tickets is another good option.  There are also telephone based services which you may use.  You can actually call 139 or send an SMS to them as per instructions in http://www.indianrail.gov.in/139.html to get a status update.

As I have answered in another thread erail.in gives you convenience and I have never seen it being down in the last 6-7 years so thats a pretty reliable source (with convenience too).

Answer (score 3):

Simply go to this site - https://www.pnr-status.info/

Why this site best among all pnr status checking site? cause its not just showing confirm ticket pnr status but also showing seat/berth type eg - CNF/D1/7/WS

ws means - Window Seat

[image]

Comment: Are you in any way associated with PNR Status?

Comment: Nope :) 

I am frequent traveler of Indian Railways and this site really helpful that's why I share here